# Pluralising foreign words

Tags: plural-forms

I am writing a novel whose background is a foreign country. Some people say that I should not pluralise foreign words, but in my case it becomes quite difficult to grab the whole meaning of a sentence if the nouns (even if they are foreign words) are not pluralised. Should I pluralised them by adding an 's' at the end?

Comment: How to treat foreign and loanwords is largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Comment: As choster says, it depends on style and also on which language.  Could you provide an example sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the context. It is a common practice that if the foreign language being borrowed into the work is Latin, Latin grammar rules apply. Similarly, you might also want to use French declension for French nouns, French being an important source of loanwords following Latin.

Generally speaking, you should pluralize the word if it is not in Latin or French, because as you are writing a text in English, the words should adhere to the rules of English grammar. But exceptions are not uncommon. If the language of the country where your story is set does not have the plural (or employs zero plural) and your context suggests that the noun at issue is embedded in a unique cultural setting, it is likely the original noun is preferred.

Two concepts in translation theory might be helpful here: domestication and foreignization. If you want to evoke an exotic feel in your readers, you might find the undeclined noun to fit the style better.

P.S. I would also like to add that if by any chance your user name is a transcription of さゆり and indicative of you being from Japan, and the language you are inquiring about is Japanese, I would say this matter is then up to you and your editor. Many texts about Japan or translated from Japanese tend to do a domesticating job and adopt English rules, but works with undeclined transcribed Japanese nouns are also common. Anyways, if my guess about your name is wide of the mark, forget this part.

Comment: Maybe because I have been using French since age 10, I would feel uneasy about  writing "gateaus" and not "gateaux".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good point. I think French does enjoy a special status, being an important source of loanwords following Latin.

Comment: Thank you, Eddie and everybody else. Your points are very insightful. I had not thought about them before but from now on I will always consider them. Yes, indeed the background of my story is Japan and language Japanese, but since I am writing it in English, I believe that following the English grammar rules is a very good policy to adopt.

Comment: Your first paragraph is too sweeping. Pluralization from classical and foreign languages is not consistent across all regions and domains: radio *antennas* but insect *antennae*, database *schemas* but philosophical *schemata*, childlike  *cherubs* but beastlike *cherubim*. In general usage, you will get further with *opuses* than *opera*, and *apparatuses* than *apparatus*, and different style manuals will opine differently on *apparatchiki*, *soprani*, or *leitmotive*.

Comment: @choster Absolutely. Point taken. Your examples are right on the nose. It is a tricky issue. I will give you that. I remember myself having a moment of pause choosing between cherubs and cherubim in my writing the other day.

Comment: @Eddie, choster, Michael Harvey Very valid points. I think the key here is to take into account the 'foreign language'. The Japanese language does not present a plural form to its nouns, well at least not in the way a Latin or Germanic language express themselves. As I am also working in a project with Portuguese language (Brazil), it will look odd if I write the plural of the word 'conquistador' - conquistadors, instead of 'conquistadores'

Comment: A certain Italian toasted sandwich is universally called "a panini" in Britain.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have to say I find your using _universally_ and _in Britain_ in the same sentence interesting. The oxymoron is avoidable, I'd say.

Comment: Something cannot be universal in Britain? "universal1 ADJECTIVE 1Relating to or done by all people or things in the world **or in a particular group**;    [Universal- Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/universal)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It's probably just me being pedantic, having tutored SAT/AP for years. This usage would be considered an oxymoron in SAT/AP. Anyways this is beside the point.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I can't be certain why I have no issue at all with, say, "We have universal health care in Japan". My hunch is that in "it is universally called 'a panini' in Britain" the usage of the word concerns not only Britain but the wider anglophone at large which I would take to be the implied scope of "universal". Just my two cents.

Comment: Smartphones Universal Among Germany's Teens; this frugality, however, is not so universal among the Dutch as it was formerly; the capacity for endosporulation is universal among phototrophic heliobacteria; our results suggest that the basic mechanism and function of receptor clustering is universal among bacterial species

Comment: Getting back to the original point, I'd tend to adopt as a helpful guide using English plural forms if the word has been adopted into **general** English usage. That is, I would tend to write "cherubs" rather than "cherubim" and "opuses" rather than "opera." On the other hand, I would most likely use the proper plural form of the source language if a loanword has a restricted meaning in English that points to its source language. So I would likely write "conquistadores" rather than "conquistadors." I do not say that this is a rule. It just seems to be a frequently helpful guideline.