# "Ramen" or "ramens" in "He bought a pack of ramen(s)"

Tags: uncountable-nouns

1. He bought a pack of ramen.
2. He bought a pack of ramens.
3. He bought two packs of ramen.
4. He bought two packs of ramens.
5. He bought a ramen.
6. He bought two ramens.

---

Which ones are grammatical?

Comment: "Ramen" is not a countable noun.  Hopefully this subject is familiar to you, but if not: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns

Comment: You've already answered your own question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pluralising foreign words](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/185724/pluralising-foreign-words)

Comment: I would (and do) treat it in the same way we treat its Italian cousin, spaghetti which would make #2, #4 & #5 incorrect.  "Ramen" is the singular and plural.  #6 "He bought two ramens" is correct because it is implying multiple portions / plates / orders / etc.  of ramen/(spaghetti).

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of ramen. [Cambridge Dictionary]

---

ramen
noun [ U ]  uk/ˈrɑː.men/
a Japanese meat or fish soup containing noodles (= long thin strips made from flour, water, and egg) and vegetables

---

As ramen is an uncountable noun, we should not put 's' at the end of 'ramen'.